# Different date results from arrow library in python

Tags: python, datetime, python-arrow

```
(Pdb) arrow.get('2016-01-01')
<Arrow [2016-01-01T00:00:00+00:00]>
(Pdb) arrow.get('20160101')
<Arrow [1970-08-22T08:01:41+00:00]>
```

So, I want my function to be able to use `arrow` library in python to parse date strings. However, as can be seen from above code, it gives different results based on whether `-` is present in the date string or not. How can I modify it so that it gives same results for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply provide a format string for the second object

```
arrow.get('20160101', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

The library probably defaults to the iso standard date format, but if you arent using that, you need to tell it how to interpret the string.

In the REPL

```
>>> arrow.get('2016-01-01')
<Arrow [2016-01-01T00:00:00+00:00]>
>>> arrow.get('20160101', 'YYYYMMDD')
<Arrow [2016-01-01T00:00:00+00:00]>
```

To use common call when the dashes are present or not, you could strip out the dashes

```
import arrow
vals = ['2016-01-01', '20160101']

for v in vals:
    d = v.replace('-', '')
    print(arrow.get(d, 'YYYYMMDD'))
```

Comment: thanks @Paul! I want the code to flexibly handle either format. Is there a way for it to handle either with or without `-`

Comment: um its a bit hacky but you could just strip out (or conversely add) the `-` chars.